# OR condition in css for screen width and parent div width, . Media query based on parent element width

Tags: javascript, html, css, media-queries

How to write media query based on screen width and parent element width .

currently i create a `php` plugin which generate some `html` output . That `html` out put is responsive ,for that i write some media query . But when i am using this plugin in another web page or website this is not fully responsive , because of parent `div` element's `width` in that webpage .
i know how to get parent element `width` using **javascript** :

`var width= $(".mydiv").parent().width();`

(1) My question is, it is possible to write or condition in `css` so that it will check either the screen width is less than **450**(test value) or the parent `div` width is less than **450** then apply certain `css`

(2) Is it possible to use `css` only for that rule .

please see the code .

```
.row::after {
 content: "";
 clear: both;
 display: block;
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 725px) {
    /* For mobiles: */
    .col-m-1 {width: 8.33%;}
    .col-m-2 {width: 16.66%;}
    .col-m-3 {width: 25%;}
    .col-m-4 {width: 33.33%;}
    .col-m-5 {width: 41.66%;}
    .col-m-6 {width: 50%;}
    .col-m-7 {width: 58.33%;}
    .col-m-8 {width: 66.66%;}
    .col-m-9 {width: 75%;}
    .col-m-10 {width: 83.33%;}
    .col-m-11 {width: 91.66%;}
    .col-m-12 {width: 100%;}
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 768px) {
    /* For desktop: */
    .col-1 {width: 8.33%;}
    .col-2 {width: 16.66%;}
    .col-3 {width: 25%;}
    .col-4 {width: 33.33%;}
    .col-5 {width: 41.66%;}
    .col-6 {width: 50%;}
    .col-7 {width: 58.33%;}
    .col-8 {width: 66.66%;}
    .col-9 {width: 75%;}
    .col-10 {width: 83.33%;}
    .col-11 {width: 91.66%;}
    .col-12 {width: 100%;}
}


    <div class="row">
    <div class="col-3   col-m-3 cub-menu">html sidebar elements</div>
    <div class="col-9  col-m-9">html main elements </div>


</div>
```

currently this is work based on screen width . But when my plugin run on websites then this row div become under other div for example

```
<div class='parrent-clas-something'>
     <div class="col-3   col-m-3 cub-menu">html sidebar elements</div>
    <div class="col-9  col-m-9">html main elements </div>

</div>
```

so what i need is the query is like `[@media only screen and (min-width: 768px) || parent element width >768]{`
......

} 
please help .

Comment: i already used media query .but it not about the screen width . it's about combination of screen width and parent div width .

Comment: i edited the question .please read.

Answer (score 1):

You can add css attribues with jQuery too.

```
if (width<450){
 $(".mydiv").css({
  height: '450px',
  backgroun: '#000',
  position: 'absolute'
})
} 
// or ...
$(".mydiv").parent().css ....
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, possible

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 450px) {
body {
    you css rules here
}
}
```

Comment: I don't think this will work if the parent element have width 350px and screen has width 1280px.